# implode the array by AND in between

Tags: php

I have this

```
$myarr = Array(
    0 => "Person.id = PL.id AND AIG.id = PL.key,"
    1 => "start_date BETWEEN  '$startDate' AND  '$endDate'",
    2 => "J = 78349",   
    3 => "text is not null;"
)
```

I want to implode this array with an AND like

```
implode("AND", $myarr)
```

But it doesnt but AND between the 4 elements of array. How would I put an AND between these 4 elements of the array.

Comment: Note that values shouldn't be interpolated directly into a statement. Instead, use a prepared statement (such as created by [`PDO::prepare`](http://php.net/PDO.prepare)) and put placeholders (named or positional) in the string. You can construct an array of parameter values at the same time you construct the expression array that you're imploding, then use the parameter array when the query is [executed](http://php.net/PDOStatement.execute).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$string = implode(" AND ",$myarr);
```

that should work fine. It will write the output to $string.